# Local storage in js is getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm setting up a login page and want to store all the user details in local storage. My data is getting overwritten and not storing as array.

I tried to push it using stringify but it is not working.

I expect it to be user1, user 2 and not user1 overwriting user2

```js
var name1 = new Array();
var pw = new Array();
var x = 0;
// storing input from register-form
function registervalidate() {
  name1[x] = document.getElementById('name1').value;
  pw[x] = document.getElementById('pw').value;

  if (name1[x] == "") {
    alert("Please enter a name");
  } else if (pw[x] == "") {
    alert("Please enter a password");
  } else {

    localStorage.setItem('name1', name1);
    localStorage.setItem('pw', pw);
    alert("Registered Successfully")

  }
  x++;
}


// check if stored data from register-form is equal to entered data in the   login-form
function login() {

  // stored data from the register-form
  var storedName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name1', JSON.stringify(name1)) || []);
  var storedPw = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pw', JSON.stringify(pw)) || []);

  // entered data from the login-form
  var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
  var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw');

  // check if stored data from register-form is equal to data from login form
  if (userName.value == storedName && userPw.value == storedPw) {
    alert('Successfully Logged in ');
    window.location.assign("Apply Now.html");
  } else {
    alert('Error! Enter correct Username and Password');
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not make sense `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name1', JSON.stringify(name1))` You need  `localStorage.getItem('name1')` Only stringify if something is an object

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: var storedName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name1',) || []);
    var storedPw = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pw')|| []);
    storedName.push(name1);
    storedPw.push(pw);
I changed it to this and tried

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting random code in a comment

Comment: and in the register validate changed it to
  localStorage.setItem('name1', JSON.stringify(name1));
        localStorage.setItem('pw', JSON.stringify(pw));
            alert("Registered Successfully")

Comment: Why would you have more than one userid and password per user? Also it is completely insecure to store userid and password in localStorage

Comment: If it's an array you need `var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name1'))`

Comment: This is for a task. I need to create an online portal for applying passport.
So multiple users will register and all the data has to be stored in local storage.